# how to find if any of the word from a word set is present in which file from a set of files in unix or linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose I have set of files

```
fSet: f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, ........... f100
```

and I set have words

```
wSet: w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, ...........w100
```

How I may list files which has one or more word from wSet?

and further

how may I may make a report which not only list files but mentions respective containing words?

and further

how I may handle if word may have special symbol like ip address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
egrep 'w1|w2|...|w100' f1 f2 ... f100
```

Or better, put your words into a file and do

```
grep -f filewithwords f1 f2 ... f100
```

Comment: in case all files are in same directory I can even use `egrep 'w1|w2|...|w100' /path/to/dir/*`. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
grep --files-with-matches -e w1 -e w2 -e w3 -e w4 -e w5 f1 f2 f3
```

put the words in a file:

```
:> cat input
w1
w2
w3
w4
w5

:> grep --files-with-matches --file=input f1 f2 f3
f1
f3

:> grep -o --file=input f1 f2 f3
f1:w2
f3:w4
f3:w5
```